# Import bookmarks to firefox from txt file

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have a txt file with a bunch of links in it and I want to import them as bookmarks in firefox.

I tried the import feature of the bookmarks manager, but it only import from an html file.

Is there some kind of script that would enable me to directly import to firefox bookmarks or create an properly formated html file from my text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally did is create an html file with all the links and importing the html file in my bookmarks. It worked great.

Comment: Is there an authoritative document describing the said HTML file syntax? Or would I have to reverse-engineer it?

Comment: Netscape html bookmark format, also used by internet explorer when exporting

Answer (score 12):

Bookmarks can be cut, copied and pasted from firefox's bookmark manager directly.

In your case, open up the text file, select all the links then go to firefox's library and click a desired folder. Then inside the folder just paste it.

I know this answer is old, but hopefully others in the future can find it because even now (March 2017), there isnt a page to explain this

Comment: Related finding: [Saving a list of Firefox 3 bookmarks](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Bookmarks#Saving_a_list_of_Firefox_3_bookmarks), which may be the only other documentation that indirectly noted this trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have created an online tool to import a list of bookmarks from plain text.

Check it our at [atkinsio.com](https://atkinsio.com/bookmarks-html-generator/).
The GitHub is open source if you would like to make something similar yourself.

Comment: Your effort is appreciated, but as for now, the tags of the file aren't closed properly. So the resulting HTML wouldn't be _well-formed_.

Comment: @zx485 Thanks for the heads up. I have reviewed the correct structure and pushed a fix.